# Laravel, не выводит модель один к одному?

Tags: laravel-5.6

Столкнулся с таким моментом
Есть модель **Ticket**
id
user_id
status_id
created_at
updated_at

Есть модель **Claimant**
id
ticket_id
info
created_at
updated_at

В моделе Ticket есть метод

```
public function claimant()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Claimant::class);
}
```

Выполняю код в тинкере

```
$ticket = App\Ticket::find(46)
$ticket->claimant->info
```

Выводит как положено **info** из **Claimant**
А если выполняю запрос

```
$tickets = App\Ticket::with(['claimant:id,info'])
                  ->where('user_id',704)
                  ->where('status_id', '>', 0)->get();
```

То выводит

```
App\Ticket {#917
     id: 46,
     user_id: 704,
     status_id: 1,
     created_at: "2020-04-16 02:03:47",
     updated_at: "2020-04-16 02:03:47",
     claimant: null,
   }
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Почему отношение claimant null?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.
Допустил ошибку при составлении запроса,
Нужно было сделать так:

```
$tickets = App\Ticket::with(['claimant:id,ticket_id,info'])
                  ->where('user_id',704)
                  ->where('status_id', '>', 0)->get();
```

Оказалось так, что в выборке должно присутствовать связующее поле, в моем случае ticket_id